# php array_merge not work replace the existing one

Tags: php

I know this maybe an old question in PHP, but it really hard to understanding where is the problem.

Code:

```
$cart = json_decode('{"ProductID":"3","Product_num":"1"} ',true);
$new_product = json_decode('{"ProductID":"1","Product_num":"1"} ',true);
$test = array_merge((array)$new_product,(array)$cart); 
echo json_encode($test);
```

The echo result is : {"ProductID":"3","Product_num":"1"}

**Why two php array using with combine together?** 
I only want the result being to :

```
[{"ProductID":"1","Product_num":"1"},{"ProductID":"3","Product_num":"1"}]
```

**Is it the problem of array key is same?**

***~~Update~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~***

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['shoppingCart_list'])){
    //$periodarray=$_SESSION['shoppingCart_list'];
    $periodarray = array();
    $periodarray = json_decode($_SESSION['shoppingCart_list'], true);
    $periodarray = array_merge($periodarray,array("product_id"=>$product_id,"product_qty"=>$product_qty));
    $periodjson = json_encode($periodarray);
    $_SESSION['shoppingCart_list'] = $periodjson;
}else{
    $periodarray=array();
    $periodarray = array_merge($periodarray,array("product_id"=>$product_id,"product_qty"=>$product_qty));
    $periodjson = json_encode($periodarray);
    $_SESSION['shoppingCart_list'] = $periodjson;
}
```

In the first time of $_SESSION['shoppingCart_list'] register, it present a correct array `{"product_id":"3","product_qty":"1"}`  , after that I call the function again and try to update the array, the array only show the latest one.

**Is it need to create a new array with both arrays inside?**

Comment: According to the [`array_merge` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php): *If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one.*

Comment: Yes, that is most likely the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a new array with both arrays inside...

```
$test = [$new_product,$cart]; 
echo json_encode($test);
```

As arrays are associative - you can only have 1 value in an array with a particular key, but you just want a set of the data not one merged array.

Answer (score 0):

the cart should be an Array ...

```
$cart = []; // New Array 
$cart[] = json_decode('{"ProductID":"3","Product_num":"1"} ',true); // add new Item to the cart Array
$new_product = json_decode('{"ProductID":"1","Product_num":"1"} ',true); 
$cart[] = $new_product; // add new Item to the cart Array
echo json_encode($cart);
```

the result :

> [{"ProductID":"3","Product_num":"1"},{"ProductID":"1","Product_num":"1"}]

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_push` like this

```
<?php
 $newArray = [];
 $cart = json_decode('{"ProductID":"3","Product_num":"1"} ',true);
 $new_product = json_decode('{"ProductID":"1","Product_num":"1"} ',true);
 array_push($newArray,$cart);
 array_push($newArray,$new_product);
 echo json_encode($newArray);
```